# Android apps developer nightmare on Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: android

Would like to know is anyone experience issues with random crashes with your developed app running on Samsung S3? I have my app tuned and working nicely for almost all the devices that i could think of but it keeps crashing on S3.

Comment: I think you can use [arca library](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) for investigate these issues

Comment: @laurent Give us more details. Error details, your code, logcat, etc.

Comment: i would definately love to give more details. but unfortunately these complaints are from clients. and i do not have a S3 so i can give more details. Just trying to see any fellow developers having problem with S3 too

Comment: @laurent Did you test your App on ICS and JB?

Comment: @Ahmad, yeah tested it on my ICS on Samsung Nexus. Running smoothly and Purring like a kitten. I used MAT to check out the mem usage and clear all memory leak

Comment: used ARCA , and there it is OUT OF MEM issue again. On Bitmaps. I have no idea how to really solve this on s3 , did a reduced conversion of the image and still gets OOM. Sigh. I don't want to be force to do a Bitmap.recycle on the layout images everytime an activity closes

Comment: @laurent you must have a memory leak or you do some not very smart stuff on Android. We can't help you unless you post some code and give more info.